# Track Running Apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to create iPhone app which is in background then it will track record of all app which user opens.

i.e when my app is in background and user opens music,safari,photo app
    then i want record like, music,safari,photo.

```
can we write names in file ?
```

Comment: `can we write names in file?` Yes, we can.

Comment: Hey, I don't want you to spy on me — sincerely,Your User

Comment: This is such a bad idea - if I found out an app was spying on my usage like that I would remove it and give such a bad review. Also I don't want you spying on the users who would be using my app, no mine Apple not wanting or allowing you to do this I don't want you to do this.

Comment: Please refrain from editing your question to ask a totally different one. In order to do so, create a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I get the hate in the comments but apps like Moment and other screen time tracker are doing it. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done.  Apple is very restrictive when it comes to things like this.

The way I understand it is this:

- Apple limits the API to your app (you can't affect other apps or the OS in any major way-this stop malicious behaviour)
- Your app is 'sandboxed' meaning it's on it's own, it can't see if Safari has any pages open, or monitor what game you just exited out of or anything like that.  Your app is in effect, isolated.
- You can write anything to a file, just getting what you want to write (in this case) is not possible

tl;dr.  No, your app is in it's own little 'sandbox' it can't monitor anything but itself, Apple doesn't allow it nor do they provide any programming library to do so.

Comment: @Alexis checkout Moment-Screen time tracker app, you'll be shocked, like I was